# Fast diagonal matrix creation from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, linear-algebra

Given 2 lists I would like to create a `Diagonal matrix`. 
One list will fill the `diagonal-constant` and the other will fill the matrix.

For example:

`fast_matrix([1,2], [6,7,8])`

Should output 2 matrices:

```
[2] # unused
[1, 6, 7, 8]
[6, 1, 7, 8]
[6, 7, 1, 8]
[6, 7, 8, 1]
```

and

```
[1] # unused
[2, 6, 7, 8]
[6, 2, 7, 8]
[6, 7, 2, 8]
[6, 7, 8, 2]
```

My [code makes 10000 transformations](https://repl.it/repls/DeliciousOrdinaryCharacter) in 2.5secs in my pc.

```
from pprint import pprint
import timeit

def not_so_fast_matrix(A, B):
    rt_obj = []
    for i,_ in enumerate(A):
        for z in range(len(B) + 1):
            new_from = A.copy()
            new_from.remove(A[i])
            new_list = B.copy()
            new_list.insert(z, A[i])
            rt_obj.append({'remain': new_from, 'to_list': new_list})
    return rt_obj

# pprint(not_so_fast_matrix([1,2], [6,7,8]))

A = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = ([60,70,80,90,100,200,300])
t = timeit.Timer(lambda: not_so_fast_toeplitz(A, B))
print("not_so_fast_matrix took: {:.3f}secs for 10000 iterations".format(t.timeit(number=10000)))
```

I was wondering if it can go faster using another approach.

---

`Circulant` from `scipy.linalg` looks like what I'm after but without rolling:

```
from scipy.linalg import circulant

print(circulant([1, 8,7,6])) # <- Should be inverted
outputs:
[[1 6 7 8]
 [8 1 6 7]
 [7 8 1 6]
 [6 7 8 1]]
```

Elements were shifted (pushed) right.

Comment: Are you aware of [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html)?

Comment: Yes, but for whatever reason it was slower

Comment: Have you tried it using SciPy version 1.1.0?  [Some changes were made](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7833) in that release that improved the performance of `toeplitz`.

Comment: No, it was relatively old code. I'm trying to rebuild it again using scipy. If you can please upload your approach

Comment: You can take a look at the [source code on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b63556394769a09354f21048e74e8aaf5a1ca152/scipy/linalg/special_matrices.py#L143).  Your function returns a list of dictionaries, while `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` returns a numpy array, so `toeplitz` won't be a direct replacement for your function.

Comment: Thanks I'm checking it right now. I think the only problem was that I could not make a topelitz while keeping the position of the other elements static. The other elements were rolled.

Comment: FYI: Your desired outputs are not [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).  In a Toeplitz matrix, the values in *each* diagonal have the same value.  In your desired output, only the main diagonal contains all the same value.  I recommend editing the question to remove all references to "Toeplitz" and "circulant".

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes you are right

Comment: Circulant without roll is basically what I need. It might be usefull as info

Comment: Hint: transposed and flattened matrix data is structured. Creation can be done in reverse direction. Something like repeat() and reshape() while taking a care about diagonal and one missing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transposed and flatten matrix has a structure where elements from B are repeated. This approach uses that property to create blueprint of matrix with wrong values on diagonal, and than fill diagonal with correct value.

```
import numpy

def create_matrices(A, B):
    # Create blueprint of result matrix
    n = len(B) + 1
    b = numpy.empty((n * n,), dtype=numpy.int32)
    b[:-1] = numpy.repeat(B, n + 1)
    b = b.reshape((n, n)).T  # <- added transposition
    # Change diagonal elements
    for a in A:
        m = b.copy()
        numpy.fill_diagonal(m, a)
        print(m)

create_matrices([1, 2], [6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Thanks Ante. There is a problem with the output though. It returns [[1 6 6 6]
 [6 1 7 7]
 [7 7 1 8]
 [8 8 8 1]] when it should return [[1 6 7 8]
[6 1 7 8]
[6 7 1 8]
[6 7 8 1]]

Comment: @PanosKal. I forget to add transposition. Check the line b = b.reshape...